Linear map with all eigenvalues greater than $1$ by absolute value is expansion?
TLDR: I proved that linear map with all eigenvalues such that $|\lambda|<1$ is contraction. If $A$ is invertible, how to prove that it's inverse, $A^{-1}$, is expansion?
Detailed question:

$A$ is contraction:
Let's assume that all eigenvalues of a linear map $A: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb  R^n$ have absolute values less than $1$. Then it can be shown that there exists a norm in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $A$ is contraction with respect to the metric generated by that norm.


(Proof: Denote spectral radius (maximal absolute value of eigenvalue) of $A$ with $r(A)$, and operator norm of $A$ with $||A||_0 = \sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||$. We use a fact from linear algebra that, for every $\delta >0$, there exists a norm $||\cdot||$ in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $||A||_0< r(A) + \delta$. If we take small enough $\delta$, by this fact it follows that $||A||_0<1$. Then $||A(x-y)|| \leq ||A||_0 ||x-y||$, so $A$ is contraction.)
2. All positive iterates converge to the origin:
From here, it's fairly easy to show that the positive iterates $A^nx$ of every point $x\in \Bbb R^n$ converge exponentially to the origin, i.e. that $d(A^nx, 0) < c\lambda^n$ holds for some $c>0, \lambda<1$. In this case, $c=d(x,0)=||x||$ and $\lambda=||A||_0$.


What I have trouble proving is the following: If in addition $A$ is invertible, then negative iterates $A^{-n}x$ of every point $x$ go to infinity exponentially.

For some reason I'm stuck on this, but I feel the proof should be pretty straightforward? My only idea so was that, because it holds
$||Ax|| \leq \ ||A||_0 ||x||$,
then it follows$||A^{-1}Ax|| \leq \ ||A||_0 ||A^{-1}x||$, that is,
$\frac{1}{||A||_0}||x|| \leq ||A^{-1}x||$.
Then by further iterations, we get $\frac{1}{||A||_0}^n||x|| \leq ||A^{-n}x||$, and so we have proved the proposition.
But I don't believe that the approach with multiplying the inequality of norms with $A^{-1}$ is allowed or correct, so I don't know what to do next.

instead of multiplying by $A^{-1}$, substitute $x = A^{-1}y$ and the same holds for any $y$
